# Symfony - Create group on ChoiceType with recursive table

Tags: symfony

I have an entity 'Theme" with reference on itself.
In few words, a "Theme" could have a "Theme" parent. It can only have one level.

See my table :

[image]

I want the following result

[image]

I made a custom query in the type, but it doesn't work.

```
->add('theme',
EntityType::class,
[
    'class' => Theme::class,
    'query_builder' => function (ThemeRepository $repo) use ($options) {
        $query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $query->leftJoin(
            Theme::class,    // Entity
            'c',               // Alias
            Join::WITH,        // Join type
            'p.parent = c.id' // Join columns
        );
        $query->where($query->expr()->isNotNull('p.parent'))
            ;
        return $query;
    },
    'group_by' => 'name',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
]);
```

Best i can have is this :

[image]

Maybe the problem is the "group_by" or "choice_label" property, because in reality it's the same column...but with different role :)

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "group_by" option is the good one to use in your situation. But you have to group by the parent name and not the current entry name. If you look at the the documentation for this option https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#group-by you can see that you can give a callback here !

The answer should be something similar to this :

```
[
    // ... Your other options
    'group_by' => ($choice, $key, $value) {
        if (!$choice instanceof Theme) {
            return null;
        }

        return $choice->getParent()->getName();
    }
]
```

I don't remember if you have to use the $choice or $value arguments here but I think it doesn't matter here since it's an EntityType.
Maybe an additional check will be required if your theme doesn't have a parent too.

Moreover, you will have a lot of automatic query with Doctrine here because you didn't add the parent in the result of your query. To avoid that, you can complete your query with ->addSelect('c') (your alias naming seems weird here though).